# Am i missing something, this.form.fill() doesn't seems to work for me

Tags: laravel, vue.js

My UserController Function:

```
public function profile()
{
    return auth('api')->user();
}
```

i'm working on project that frontend with vue and backend with laravel.

My Vue.js Code:

```
 import Form from 'vform';
  export default {

   data () {
    return {
      form: new Form({
        id:'',
        name: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        type:'',
        bio:'',
        photo:''
      })
    }
  },

    mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted.')
    },

    created(){
        axios.get("api/profile")
         .then( ({data}) => (this.form.fill(data)))
    }

 }
```

i try to show data in form, but when i call this function it not return the data. what i am doing wrong? i know there is problem with this function this.form.fill(data) but i don't know what actual the problem is.

Comment: Where did you define the fill method?

Comment: @dreijntjens this all method is in import file which i globally imported:  import Form from 'vform';

Comment: either your the api is not returning a result (with { data }) or the field names are different for example name <> Name

Comment: @dreijntjens field names are same. i think there is some problem with that data.